# Hide\show content goes over other spoiler buttons

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have made some spoilers that when you click on them, it will slide some information

So I clicked on spoiler1, and it did slide it but weirdly under the other spoilers..

like this:

http://gyazo.com/4571423534e2442dc960d119c668dfa8

Why does it do that and how do I fix it so the spoilers that are under the current spoiler im opening will slide down under the content?

My code:

```
        <div id="container">
    <div class="spoiler1"><span id="title1">This is Test</div>
        <span class="hide1">testttttttttttttttttttttt</span><!-- This is what opens after clicking on spoiler -->
        <br /><br />
    <div class="spoiler2"><span id="title1">This is Test</div>
        <br /><br />
    <div class="spoiler3"><span id="title1">This is Test</div>
        <br /><br />
    <div class="spoiler4"><span id="title1">This is Test</div>
        <br /><br />
        <br /><br />
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".hide1").hide();
        $(".spoiler1").show();

    $('.spoiler1').click(function(){
    $(".hide1").slideToggle();
    });

});

</script>
```

CSS:

```
#title1 {
    color: #1794c8;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    }

.spoiler1{
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #c0e6d2;
    border: 1px solid #a7c8b7;
    height: 45px;
    width: 530px;
    position: absolute;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f4f4f4;
        filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=0, offy=1);
        z-index:1;

}
.spoiler2{
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #c0e6d2;
    border: 1px solid #a7c8b7;
    height: 45px;
    width: 530px;
    position: absolute;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f4f4f4;
        filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=0, offy=1);
}
.spoiler3{
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #c0e6d2;
    border: 1px solid #a7c8b7;
    height: 45px;
    width: 530px;
    position: absolute;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f4f4f4;
        filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=0, offy=1);
}
.spoiler4{
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #c0e6d2;
    border: 1px solid #a7c8b7;
    height: 45px;
    width: 530px;
    position: absolute;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f4f4f4;
        filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=0, offy=1);
}
```

How do I fix this? :/

Thank you.

Comment: It's all CSS related. Please provide your CSS

Comment: Added the CSS  also live preview: http://justxp.plutohost.net/slyfiles/index.html

Answer (score 0):

use `z-index=1` css property on spoiler-1.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: http://justxp.plutohost.net/slyfiles/index.html I did it and even tried -1 and it didnt work so I left it as 1, and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is mangled, you should set and end tag for `span` here:

```
<div class="spoiler1"><span id="title1">This is Test</div>
```

that could be confusing the DOM and be the cause of your problem.
You have the same error on all 4 spoiler divs.

Comment: I did and no really change + after the z-index

Comment: I've checked your site, your slider is full of span, ones absolute positioned, others relative, that is why you get some overlaps others, so should not use absolute positioning if you want a flow layout where sliding an element will move the others down.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKz8y/) is what you're looking for.

The problem is in your HTML and CSS.

Use containers to divide the content and style these containers.

I've simplified the classes, etc it's easier to understand.

HTML

```
<div id="featurelist_2_wrap">
    <div class="spoiler">
        <span class="feature">Networks</span>
        <div class="hide"><span class="featurelist_3-text-margin">We have a very secure system, including secure logging in,<br>
            management, balance management and more.<br>
            We do a SQL backup every hour to protect us from our<br>
            data being lost.</span></div>
    </div>
     <div class="spoiler"><span class="feature">Networks</span>
        <div class="hide"><span class="featurelist_3-text-margin">We have a very secure system, including secure logging in,<br>
            management, balance management and more.<br>
            We do a SQL backup every hour to protect us from our<br>
            data being lost.</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="spoiler"><span class="feature">Networks</span>
        <div class="hide"><span class="featurelist_3-text-margin">We have a very secure system, including secure logging in,<br>
            management, balance management and more.<br>
            We do a SQL backup every hour to protect us from our<br>
            data being lost.</span></div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

CSS

```
.spoiler {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

.feature {
    display:block;
    background-color: #C0E6D2;
    border: 1px solid #A7C8B7;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height:45px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #F4F4F4;
    width: 530px;
}

.hide { display:none; }
```

Javascript

```
$('.spoiler').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.hide').slideToggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

New visitors try this as spoilers

HTML

```
    <p>In the movie Citizen Kane, Charles Foster Kane's last word "Rosebud" 
turns out to <span class="spoiler">be a sled.</span></p>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.reveal { cursor:pointer; }
.spoiler{ display:none; }
</style>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('<a class="reveal">&gt;&gt;</a> ').insertBefore('.spoiler');

    $("body").on("click",".reveal" ,function(){
        $(this).parents("p").children("span.spoiler").fadeIn(2500);
        $(this).parents("p").children("a.reveal").fadeOut(600);
    });

});
```

Taken from
http://css-tricks.com/fade-in-spoiler-revealer/